# I executed 'dd' on my /dev/sda and now I get "unknown filesystem" error

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem, data-recovery, dd

Yes, I know this error has been answered and solved many times; but I think I know the reason why this is happening (my bad), I just don't know how to solve it.

I was formatting and flashing some USB with 'dd' like:

```
dd if=myImage.img of=/dev/sdb1 bs=1M
```

And everything was perfectly fine until I did a big mistake:

```
dd if=myImage.img of=/dev/sda bs=1M
```

I tried to dd my **/dev/sda** filesystem, I got a message like this (not exactly this, I couldn't copy it):

```
96452+0 records in
96452+0 records out
71383424 bytes (7.1 MB) copied, 60.664 s, 495 MB/s
```

So I guess it started to overwrite the stuff in /dev/sda, then it crashed and I got this:

[image: Error]

So I guess I started writing on the primary partition, and overwrite important stuff at the beginning of the filesystem. After this, I get the:

```
Error: unknown filesystem
grub rescue >
```

From which I cannot get out of. I have tried the answers of other questions but I can't get rid of it. Any  ideas? If you need more info, just ask. It will be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it. I followed the instructions in [this link](http://linuxexpresso.wordpress.com/2010/03/31/repair-a-broken-ext4-superblock-in-ubuntu/).

Basically I had to:

```
sudo fsck.ext4 -v /dev/sda1
```

After a lot of fixing (and answering 'yes') I got a final message similar to this:

```
/dev/sda1: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
/dev/sda1: 88123/761856 files (1.5% non-contiguous), 2038341/3044128 blocks
```

Then reboot and everything was fine.